# Error when adding sqflite to flutter dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, sqflite

I was working in flutter project perfectly in android studio . but I had to use sqflite , so I added it to the dependencies in pubspec.yaml and these errors happened .

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'.
> Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.0/builder-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar
> Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/27.1.0/manifest-merger-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/4.1.0/gradle-api-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/4.1.0/databinding-compiler-common-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/4.1.0/builder-model-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/4.1.0/builder-test-api-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/27.1.0/ddmlib-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find signflinger.jar (com.android:signflinger:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/4.1.0/signflinger-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find zipflinger.jar (com.android:zipflinger:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/4.1.0/zipflinger-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/27.1.0/tracker-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/27.1.0/sdklib-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/27.1.0/layoutlib-api-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/27.1.0/dvlib-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/27.1.0/repository-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/27.1.0/shared-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/27.1.0/common-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find jetifier-processor.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find jetifier-core.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.1.0/protos-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find core-proto.jar (com.google.test.platform:core-proto:0.0.2-dev).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/test/platform/core-proto/0.0.2-dev/core-proto-0.0.2-dev.jar
> Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/4.1.0/apkzlib-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/4.1.0/apksig-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.1.0/annotations-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/4.1.0/databinding-common-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/4.1.0/baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Exception: The plugin sqflite could not be built due to the issue above.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: What gradle version and sqflite version do you use in your flutter project? 

I read this in the sqflite changelog https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite/changelog

"2018/01/04 Breaking change. Upgraded to Gradle 4.1 and Android Studio Gradle plugin 3.0.1. Older Flutter projects need to upgrade their Gradle setup as well in order to use this version of the plugin. Instructions can be found here." (from sqflite 0.3.0).

Comment: I am using gradle 5.6.2 and gradle plugin 4.1.0 and the flutter and dart plugins are latest updates .

Comment: Hmm, what about this (these versions works fine with sqflite for me):
1. What is your android gradle version? (ex. 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0') 2. What is your kotlin-gradle-plugin version? (ex. org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10) 
3. What is your distributionUrl? (ex. https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip)